# Quasiquotation and filtering using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 3:7, b = 1:5)

#   a b
# 1 3 1
# 2 4 2
# 3 5 3
# 4 6 4
# 5 7 5
```

I can use quasiquotation to select a column in my data frame like this:

```
MyVarName <- "b"
df %>% select(!!MyVarName)   

#   b
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 3
# 4 4
# 5 5
```

Cool stuff. Now, say I want to filter using quasiquotation, like this:

```
df %>% filter(!!MyVarName > 3)
```

My aim was to produce the following:

```
#   a b
# 1 6 4
# 2 7 5
```

like I'd get from `df %>% filter(b > 3)`, but instead I got,

```
#   a b
# 1 3 1
# 2 4 2
# 3 5 3
# 4 6 4
# 5 7 5
```

Even adding brackets (i.e., `df %>% filter((!!MyVarName) > 3)`) didn't help. Is it possible to use quasiquotation in `filter` in a similar way to this? If so, how is the syntax I used incorrect?

Comment: Are you trying to use strings? quasinotation assumes you have symbols or names. Use `MyVarName <- rlang::expr(b)` or `MyVarName <- rlang::sym("b")`. `select()` is an exception to many of the other functions because it always accepted strings and symbols. Both `df %>% select("b")` and `df %>% select(b)` would work, but that's not the case for most other dplyr functions.

Comment: Are you trying to use this within a function, such as where `myVarName` would be a string or a bare column name passed in as an argument?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I'm trying to use this in a function exactly as you say. I guess it's a dupe then...